# Return multiple function values in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, function

In MATLAB, I have a function file that returns multiple variables

```
function [a,b,c]= myfunc(x,y,z)
```

It utilizes an infinite `while` loop that runs until it reaches a max number of iterations or until it reaches an acceptable value of relative error. So `a`, `b`, and `c` are the values of the final function, the calculated relative error, and the number of iterations. I want to know how to create an array that returns all calculated values of the function and also an array that returns all calculated values of relative error.

Comment: You will need to create an array inside your function that stores the results from each iteration, and then just make it an output of the function.

Comment: Some example would be useful.

Comment: how about returning 3 structures `a, b, c`. You can have final values at one field of structure and number of iterations as other field

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
function [a_arr,b_arr,c_arr] = myfunc(x,y,z)

a_arr=zeros(1,maxiter)

i=1;

while (i <= maxiter)

% loop elements
a_arr(i)=a;

if (errorcondition)
break;
end

i=i+1;
end
a_arr=a_arr(1:i-1);

end
```